# magento 2 how to get product (country_of_manufacture) by sku via API

Tags: magento2, attributes, rest-api

Here is the script i get the product but the country_of_manufacture is not inside in the product object.

get Product attribute from the

```
function getProduct ($sku, $token, $ch) {
    $ch = curl_init("http://m23.rayman.com/index.php/rest/V1/products/".$sku);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "GET");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: application/json", "Authorization: Bearer " . json_decode($token)));   

    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    return $result;
}
```

anyone know how to get the country_of_manufacture via rest api by sku?

Answer (score 0):

Add following code before return:

```
$result = json_decode($result, 1);
if (isset($result['custom_attributes'])) {
    foreach ($result['custom_attributes'] as $customAttribute) {
        if ($customAttribute['attribute_code'] == 'country_of_manufacture') {
            echo $customAttribute['value'];
        }
    }
}
```